# Make extra braces trigger a compiler warning error C#

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, compiler-warnings

I have the following code which is obviously a user error (extra return statement)

```
if (!await NoError()) return false;
{
    Logger.LogError("Error occured!");
    return false;
}
```

Now the extra return statement means that it returns false always regardless of there being an error or not. Is there any way to get Visual Studio 2017 to throw a compiler error or warning in this scenario?

Comment: A statement block is a valid C# construct, you're probably looking at writing an analyzer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is a compiler warning for this as it is valid C#, and there are legitimate use cases for curly braces 'by themselves'.

A code analyser like StyleCop might be able to throw a warning if you use an if/else statement without curly braces directly attached; which would catch the case in your example. In StyleCop this is covered by [rule SA1503](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop/blob/master/Project/Docs/Rules/SA1503.html).